# Finding the value of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, if-statement

I am coding a sequencer that allows you to choose which sound you want to be carried into different parts of the code. I am using an array that holds the sound ID value and if a different sound is selected, the array is reset and the value changes. Initially, I thought using this snippet would work to check what sound has been chosen:

```
    if(sounds == 1){
    //insert effect of sound value
    }
```

But, this did nothing. I then tried:

```
   sounds == [1];
```

but that had no effect at all. What code should be used when trying to execute code based on the value of an array with a single item (if that makes sense)?

Comment: Try, ```sounds[0]``` ..

Comment: `this only ends up referring to the length of the array` - no it doesn't ... if `sounds` is an array, you're basically testing if an object == 1 - which it never will .... also, the `;` in that code is a syntax error

Comment: `sounds == [1];` compares whatever `sounds` is with an array that has a single element (1), then disregards the result - it's basically a do nothing line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your concern, You want to check the value inside the array right?
In that way, You can check the values of the array by using `includes()` method.

Like:

```
sounds = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

if(sounds.includes(1)) {
   //insert effect of sound value
} else {
   // Do else thing here.
}
```

This might resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, by writing `sounds == 1` you are checking if the **size** of "sounds" array is 1 or not.

To access the value of the array element itself use:

```
sounds[0] == n
```

Count in array starts from 0, and last element will be length of array `sounds.length - 1`

Now, if I correctly understood your question itself and you want to output certain sound based on which element is chosen from array, then you could use Switch / Case. First iterate through array using `for` loop. Then declare `Switch()` expression. Then, write what kind of output / action should happen when `case` happens.

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
   Switch (sounds[i]) {                    
      case 1:              // imagine sound ID is 1                                  
         //output code     // this code will get executed     
         break;                 
      case 2:              // sound ID is 2
         //output code     // this code will get executed
         break;
      case 3:              // sound ID is 2
         //output code     // this code will get executed
         break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on our question, you are saying you have an array of sound values. I imagine it looks like

`var sounds = ["1"]`

If this is the case, you can do `sounds.includes("1")` to see it `"1"` is present.